# how do I do the following hibernate mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following DB schema :

```
table a {
    id,
    state
}

table b {
    id,
    a_id,
    is_valid,
    amount
}
```

I want to have a hibernate mapping where I fetch values from table b only if a.state has a certain value.  This is the hibernate mapping i had (used the example from the [jBoss Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html))

```
<discriminator column="state" type="string"/>
<subclass name="ClassB" discriminator-value="VALUE1">
    <join table="b">
        <key column="a_id"/>
        <property name="amount" column="amount"/>
    </join>
</subclass>
```

When i did this, my xml showed a syntax error stating that a hierarchy must be followed.

Is what I'm doing correct and if not, it would be great if someone could show me the way forward. Thanks.

P.S - more than one entry in table b will have the a_id column.  However only one row in b will have the is_valid value set and its enough if i get this row in my POJO

Comment: it would help if you posted the full mapping and the java objects behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are mapping a table per subclass with discriminator strategy.  This would imply a 1 - 1 row correlation between table a and table b, where the primary key of table b (the subclass) would also be a foreign key into table a.

However, your mapping is slightly odd in that you have

```
<key column="a_id" />
```

Typically this should be

```
<key column="id" />
```

And there would be no "a_id" column.

However, your db design looks like a one-to-many relationship rather than a subclass relationship.

Without your objects themselves, i can't really say what it is you're trying to do.

Take a look at the hibernate docs on inheritence.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html

Comment: yes it is a one to many relationship.  Many rows in table b will have the same a_id key. didn't want to use the one-to-many mapping as getting an object of ClassA would fetch all the Objects of ClassB from the db and i didn't want to do that. if you still want i can post the java objects.

Comment: you can post them, but they <subclass> element is not really useful for what you are trying to do.  You're trying to only fetch the collection if a particular column is set to a particular value.  That's not really something hibernate will do for you that i know of.

Comment: What i did was put it in a different hibernate mapping as I was clubbing too many things in one hibernate mapping